# iPhoto won't open

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, photos.app

When I tried to open iPhoto, it says that I needed to update to the latest version.

Im using OS X Yosemite system.

When I search on App Store it says that "*The item you've requested is not currently available*".

Answer (score 7):

iPhoto *and Aperture* are not supported any more and have been removed from the app store.

From wikipedia ([here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhoto)):

> On April 8, 2015, Apple released OS X Yosemite 10.10.3, which includes the new Photos app. iPhoto and Aperture were discontinued and removed from the Mac App Store.

The successor app **Photos** was just released – [on the corresponding page at apple.com](http://www.apple.com/support/mac-apps/photos/) you'll find further information about this release.

Answer (score 0):

I just went through this with a friend of mine. We found and installed iPhoto from the App Store under Purchases.

Answer (score 0):

1) Launch the terminal (don't be afraid, type "terminal" on spotlight or in /Application/Utilities/Terminal(.app)

2) type :
/Applications/iPhoto.app/Contents/MacOS/iPhoto

Found this at 
http://www.simplehelp.net/2015/05/01/how-to-install-iphoto-in-yosemite-os-x-10-10/